# Rest edition or standard?

Tags: rest, symfony

We are going to start a project that will mostly rely on services. Is it better to start with the Symfony2 REST edition or the standard one ? Or that´s just a starting composer file so it´s not very important at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should just use the normal `Symfony2` version. There's **no reason** to take the `Symfony2 REST Edition` if you don't want to create a `REST Service`. From what I understood from your question is that your web application simply rely on services. Your Web application itself is **NOT** a REST Service from what I understood.

Comment: No, sorry if I didn't make it clear, we must produce rest services.